# How do I move a user from group assignment to individual using the Okta API?

Tags: okta, okta-api

In order to remove Users from an App in Okta using the API, their access first must be changed from "Group" to "Administrator".

[image]

Selecting Administrator then calls their access "Individual" in the table. Those users can then be removed from the application using the API.

I'm wondering how I can perform the move from Group to Individual for a user via the API as well? It doesn't appear to be in the Apps or Users API: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/postman-collections/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's counter intuitive but you can add the user to the app with a `scope` of `USER` to change their access from group to individual. With the oktakit ruby gem:

```
client.assign_user_to_application_for_sso(
  okta_app_id,
  {
    id: okta_user_id,
    scope: "USER"
  }
)
```

You would then be free to deprovision:

```
client.remove_user_from_application(okta_app_id, okta_user_id)
```